# django url error when rendring a template

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am writing an application with django. everything has been working fine and I have been working in another page of the application then I decided to come back to the home page and I got this error.

```
Reverse for 'more' with keyword arguments '{u'slug': u''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

Everything was working perfectly and I cant seen to understand why.
**If** I change the template to another template lets say hello.html the whole url responds well but once I change it back to index.html I get that same error. any help would be appreciated

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
from posts.models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
            "image",
            "draft",
            "publish",
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
results = Post.objects.all().filter(draft=False).filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())
que = request.GET.get("q")
if que:
    results =results.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=que)|
        Q(content__icontains=que)).distinct()
paginator = Paginator(results, 8) # Show 25 contacts per page
pages ="page"
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    query = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    query = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    query = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
context = {
    "objects": query,
    "pages": pages
}
template = 'index2.html'
return render(request,template,context)
```

**html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
    {% block content %}
    <h1>This is Home</h1>
    {% include 'messages.html'%}
    <form method="GET" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="q" value="{{ request.GET.q }}" placeholder="search" >
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
    </form>

    {% for obj in objects %}
  <h1>  <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.title }}</a></h1><br>
  {% if obj.image %}
  <img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" alt="{{ obj.title }}" width="250" height="250"><br>
  {% endif %}

   {{ obj.content|safe|truncatewords:20 }}
    {{ obj.timestamp }}<br>
    {{ obj.updated }}<br>

    {% endfor %}
    <br>

    <div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if contacts.has_previous %}

            <a href="?{{ pages }}={{ objects.previous_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ objects.number }} of {{ objects.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if objects.has_next %}
            <a href="?{{ pages }}={{ objects.next_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

    {% endblock %}
```

**Absolute url in model**

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("more", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

**url pattern**

```
url(r'^$', posts_views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: The only line I see that could cause this problem is `<a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.title }}</a></h1><br>`. So we need to see the definition of `get_absolute_url()` on your `Post` object. Otherwise, you're probably using an `{% url %}` tag or `reverse()/reverse_lazy()`that you haven't shown us.

Comment: @CoryMadden I have updated the question

Comment: Thanks, it looks fine, but it looks like `Post` may not have a value for `self.slug`?

Comment: it worked fine before then suddenly stopped

Comment: Well, you had to change something. Things don't usually break for no reason.

Comment: I'm actually pretty certain that's the problem. Your regex for your URL requires at least one character, and you're not providing it, so it's giving you that error.

Comment: I removed this line and it rendered the page but I can click on any link <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.title }}</a>

Comment: then I also notice that the crsf attaches every link I try to create. for example if I create a post instead of it to slug the post it adds crsf with other text behind it like    http://127.0.0.1:8000/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=fqnBGGYFccECbCZyBCtpia2bu0iXmrFgNsNDmGDKAi28i7xIEOTZHTa9pgR2kANv&q=hdksks+&submit=Go%21

Comment: You don't need the CSRF token for GET requests.

Comment: it does the same thing in my Post method also

Comment: Remove `{% csrf_token %}` from your form and reload the page(making sure you take out the csrf from the URL first).

Comment: I removed it but still nothing

Comment: I think @CoryMadden has already identified the problem, you have at least one `Post` with no slug. How are you creating the slugs? It must be automatic, since `PostForm` doesn't have it as a field.

Comment: do I clear the database?

Comment: No need for that, just do something like `Post.objects.filter(slug='')` in the Django shell and you'll identify those posts.

Comment: I figured out I tampered with the title field and the slug was empty. I deleted it from the admin

Comment: Cool, so the problem is solved and the index renders well again?

Comment: yes it does render well.